# How can I change font without changing the layout?

Tags: tables

I have created a table by use of a template. However, I want the whole table to have the same font, not the sans serif font. I have tried to change the command from \textsf to \text, but that just makes the text continue outside the box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp,,amsmath, longtable}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\begin{document}
    
    %% Set up counters for questions
    %% 
    \newcounter{qnumber}
    \setcounter{qnumber}{0}
    \stepcounter{qnumber}
    \newcommand{\yesno}{\textsf{Yes}~~\textsf{No} {\Large ~$\Box$}~~~~   {\Large $\Box$}}
    
    %% we now define the questions
    \newcommand{\question}[1]{
        \hfill \relax1.\theqnumber\hfill\hfill &\textsf{#1} &{\small\yesno} \stepcounter{qnumber}\\ \hline
    }
    
    %% we now define the questions
    \newcommand{\heading}[1]{
        1.0 &\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\bf\text{#1}}\\ \hline %
    }
    \newcommand{\divider}{\hline}
    \begin{longtable}{|c| p{10cm}|p{1.5cm}|}
        \divider
        Nr.&Would you get vaccinated in this situation? &  \\
        \divider\divider
        
        \question{Now, one year later, a vaccine is available. If you and enough people in Econotopia get vaccinated, fewer people will die and restrictions will be repealed. Therefore, your actions will have an effect.}
        \question{Because a lot of people took the vaccine, the authorities in Econotopia are introducing a system where vaccinated people will be able to go to restaurants, small concerts and be allowed to work from the office and meet physically at school.}
        \question{To get more people vaccinated, the authorities are now offering 100€ if you get vaccinated.}
        \question{Until now, also unvaccinated people have had the same rights of freedom as vaccinated people if they got tested for the virus 2 times a week. The authorities are now removing this possibility. Therefore, if you are not vaccinated, you cannot go to for example concerts, restaurants, or being able to go to your school or your job physically.}
        \question{Due to a new wave of hospitalization, the authorities in Econotopia introduce more powerful means to get more people vaccinated. Therefore, in addition to not having the same freedom as vaccinated people, you must pay a monthly fee of 50€ if you do not get the vaccine.}
        \question{On the news, the anchor can tell that the side effects from the vaccine can cause death for some people. Therefore, by getting vaccinated you have risks from the side effects as well as the risks from getting the virus.}
        
    \end{longtable}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\textrm` instead or just remove completely the command `\textsf` (and the curly braces of it).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 4):

To not use the sans serif font just completely remove `\textsf` (`\text` is provided by `amsmath` for use in maths and forms a box, that's why line breaking doesn't work anymore).

I took the liberty to change a few other things:

- The boxes under "Yes" and "No" are now centred correctly
- I removed all the ugly rules from your table, instead I used the rules provided by `booktabs`
- I set up `longtable` correctly (with `\endhead` and `\endfoot`) to get the first row and the rule at the bottom repeated on every page the `longtable` might need.
- I removed the unused `\heading` command (that one contained the *evil* instruction `\bf` that shouldn't be used, it is deprecated since more than a decade).
- I removed the spurious spaces from your `\question` definition (the uncommented line endings after `{` and `}` will result in a space there).
- I moved your definitions into the preamble to better separate code from content.
- I moved the `\stepcounter` to a more sensible place and changed it to `\refstepcounter` (this way you could use a `\label` to later reference it).
- I removed the `\hfill` commands from `\question`, those weren't doing anything useful (column alignment should be specified in the table preamble). See more about the peculiarities of those `\hfill`s at the end of this answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp,,amsmath, longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{latexsym}

%% Set up counters for questions
%% 
\newcounter{qnumber}
\setcounter{qnumber}{0}
\newcommand*\tickbox{{\Large$\Box$}}%
\newcommand*\yesno
  {\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{~~}c@{}}Yes&No\\\tickbox&\tickbox\end{tabular}}%

%% we now define the questions
\newcommand{\question}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{qnumber}1.\theqnumber
    & #1
    & \small\yesno
    \\
    \addlinespace
}

\begin{document}
    
    
    \begin{longtable}{c p{10cm} c}
      \toprule
        Nr.&Would you get vaccinated in this situation? &  \\
      \midrule
      \endhead
      \bottomrule
      \endfoot
      \question{Now, one year later, a vaccine is available. If you and enough people in Econotopia get vaccinated, fewer people will die and restrictions will be repealed. Therefore, your actions will have an effect.}
      \question{Because a lot of people took the vaccine, the authorities in Econotopia are introducing a system where vaccinated people will be able to go to restaurants, small concerts and be allowed to work from the office and meet physically at school.}
      \question{To get more people vaccinated, the authorities are now offering 100€ if you get vaccinated.}
      \question{Until now, also unvaccinated people have had the same rights of freedom as vaccinated people if they got tested for the virus 2 times a week. The authorities are now removing this possibility. Therefore, if you are not vaccinated, you cannot go to for example concerts, restaurants, or being able to go to your school or your job physically.}
      \question{Due to a new wave of hospitalization, the authorities in Econotopia introduce more powerful means to get more people vaccinated. Therefore, in addition to not having the same freedom as vaccinated people, you must pay a monthly fee of 50€ if you do not get the vaccine.}
      \question{On the news, the anchor can tell that the side effects from the vaccine can cause death for some people. Therefore, by getting vaccinated you have risks from the side effects as well as the risks from getting the virus.}
    \end{longtable}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### What are those `\hfill` really doing?

In the original question (and earlier versions of this answer) the macro `\question` was defined with multiple `\hfill` calls, like this:

```
\newcommand{\question}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{qnumber}\hfill 1.\theqnumber\hfill\hfill
    & #1
    & \small\yesno\\
    \addlinespace
}
```

Let's take a closer look on what those do. First they overwrite any alignment specified in the table preamble (since for instance the `c`entred columns use the "weaker" `\hfil`). This is nothing really bad in general, but defeats the purpose of specifying table alignments in the table's preamble (which in this case was `c` anyway).

So what do they do? Each `\hfill` adds a stretching space with second order infinity stretch (one infinity more than `\hfil`, Knuthian TeX knows three orders of infinity). So when a table column is wider than its contents these `\hfill` will stretch (and the `\hfil` used by LaTeX's columns won't do anything). So `\hfill\hfill` adds two parts of stretch and `\hfill` adds one. Now one could think that this leads to slightly off centre columns in this case, since we find two `\hfill` on the right and one on the left. But in the attempt to ignore trailing spaces in a cell LaTeX uses `\unskip` to remove the last space, but here the second `\hfill` is removed. The result is a column with one part stretch on both sides, so centred, so why making all this hassle instead of just using a `c` column?

How could we create a slightly off centre column? We could've prevented the removal of the second `\hfill` by putting something that is not a skip behind it (for instance an empty `\mbox{}`, or a zero-width `\kern0pt`) or (and this is how I guess this code came into existence in the first place) we put yet another `\hfill` there that gets removed by the `\unskip`.

Comment: Wow! That looks absolutely fantastic. Thank you so very much for your help. I hope it´s okay if I use your edited table in my paper.

Comment: Furthermore, do you or anyone know if it is possible to instead of having numbers 1.1, 1.2, ..., have Q.1, Q.2, ...?

Comment: Sure. Just have `\refstepcounter{qnumber}\hfill Q.\theqnumber\hfill\hfill` instead of `\refstepcounter{qnumber}\hfill 1.\theqnumber\hfill\hfill`.

Comment: By the way, what is the reason for having two `\hfill`s @Skillmon? One shall suffice, right?

Comment: @Niranjan Well, since the material is used inside a `c` column, none should suffice for centred alignment. I was assuming OP tries to get a slightly off-centre adjustment (two parts right one part left). But in fact in this case (since there is an implicit `\unskip` at the end of each cell) the second `\hfill` gets removed, so this has the same effect as `\hfill<stuff>\hfill`. I guess whoever created this template had no idea how the internals work in this case and found out by trial and error that it works this way. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @SivertDahle would be strange to post an answer and then forbid you to use it :) Go ahead and use it. The license of code posted on this site is a CC BY-SA, my code is dual licensed as beerware. Pick whichever fits your needs best (or be a bit rude and don't tell where you got this at all).

Comment: Hahah! Agian, thank you very much @Skillmon!